# Borderline between "translucent" and "transparent"

Tags: adjectives, word-difference

I'm trying to understand the meaning of the word "translucent" when used to describe optical properties of objects. Does it mean "I can see through" or "the light can go through"?

I understand that water is *transparent* (and colorless), whereas iron is *opaque*. What about colored glass: it's still *transparent*, right?

[image]

Now, let's take the same colored glass and turn it into a shape which distorts light. Does it become *translucent*, or is it still *transparent*?

[image]

Finally, what about wax? It's certainly not *transparent*, but some light manages to go through. Is it *translucent* then?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should use only *one of* "transparent", "translucent", and "opaque" when describing objects, otherwise it can get confusing.  A window is *transparent*.  A window with a piece of white paper over it is *translucent*.  A window with a black curtain over it is *opaque*.

If you have a colored *glass* through which you can clearly distinguish objects, I would call it "transparent" (or at least "see-through") even if the images of those objects are distorted by the glass.

[image: colored glass]

If you are talking about actual stone *marble*, cut thin enough to allow light to be seen through, I would call it *translucent*:

[image: marble lamp]

Of course, objects can be *partly* transparent/translucent, especially if made of mixed materials.

Comment: I'm not talking about actual stone marble, but about toy marbles made of glass. If I understand you correctly, those are *transparent* by your standards, right?

Comment: Yes -- although the challenge is that most toy marbles are made of mixed materials, so it's not always *clear*.  Like [this marble](http://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/8-EAAOSwPCVX3l-j/s-l225.jpg) made of clouded glass, which I would call *translucent*.  I would say if you can see the *outlines* of objects through the glass, I would call it at least *semi-transparent*.

Comment: You seem to disagree with the other answer which called my marbles *translucent* (and I specifically mean the marbles in my question, made of homogeneous clear colored glass).

Comment: Yes which is why I put my opinion in a separate answer.  I guess the *true* answer is that it can be a matter of personal preference.  Sorry if this confuses the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of [*translucent*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/translucent) says:

> 1 permitting the passage of light:
>   a: clear, transparent <translucent water>
>   b: transmitting and diffusing light so that objects beyond **cannot be seen clearly**

while [*transparent*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transparent):

> having the property of transmitting light without appreciable scattering so that bodies lying beyond are **seen clearly**

<sub>(Note that 1a. of translucent basically says that transparent objects are also translucent)</sub>

I'd argue that in your case:

- water is transparent and translucent
- colored glass is transparent and translucent (there are rare cases, depending on the ambient light and the color of the object behind it, where the object cannot be seen - then it's not really transparent)
- the marbles are translucent, but not transparent
- the hot wax is also translucent, but not transparent

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is there a word which I could use to tell apart the marbles and the wax? Wax is *matted* and marbles are *clear*?

Comment: *Matted* is indeed what you're looking for. I'm not sure if *clear* can be used for colored objects.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I'd say that wax is **matte**. "Matted" sounds like tangled fur.

Comment: It might be that glass technically qualifies as translucent, but I think its transparency trumps it. In other words 'completely transparent' subsumes 'partially transparent' . 
To put it another way, I would never describe a clear glass window as translucent, but your picture of wax candles exactly illustrates the word. 
The marbles are a little difficult - I'd call those 'clear glass marbles' as opposed to those 'milky' ones you sometimes see. . . .